# On the transformation of Black-Scholes equation in to a dimensionless system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finance

Let me show the supposition extracted from [S.-P. Zhu et al. / Computers and Mathematics with Applications 64 (2012)](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271503/1-s2.0-S0898122112X00191/1-s2.0-S0898122112005378/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEGYaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIH%2FOsCI0Lql%2BVmN2fR%2BTuRui%2FFWD73f0JCv31q0hntt0AiBg1s1IUxcZQ66kVJp202D1nvl8zxZsuKFDU0i2XXOdlyq7BQif%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIM18xLv4hCXSIUefGLKo8F4v8ousCBSz1ZIYpacvBqM2szo8fcobvTpWrQz7S7E73GiDwlkVnksPOcZZI9VY9UcJxfClE3hjnQtwmQRiWfI0Q7XeUJXW4jiQpy2sTe80tRBcwDhntLLx8jdkSUQXLZz6Vny94l6KJRsPAbdf%2F7CcsiEh3nvi4IlUf62uoyPT2IEJS0Vy25O0VhbKYjUBI5yqcHurc13%2FodjOw7LxBbKvGY0WblDa1tc5hXnYqWlKL9k9klzc46cI1jPmoZV7IkRI55HfZc%2FszkKEMXuEBGVjnw%2Fz7fmJha7LucZBiGmB5hvcM6T9aqpnbVz8wVt3IiLkarPCFEftMtOYIFi%2BddTwQi5tXMML9BoBSOK1Ate4FLC7ZWtGjC%2FPIpkyf1tPwuRnptMzvGiCIXvsg5JTnHgHLLInXOfXnfubscTKbs2xElRPSAF9rOy4sc8Nesjd4W5PrL%2Bfl%2BCZR8KhICI1L%2FjzWjGKScUceusBIySOqisi%2FTDHqpteWX7Cz8L5jEzcTxPqVhVnxXwitBwdAZkqZ9HfTyhLUj1hZzIlRE1P7%2BE%2Bx23TW5h3vu558%2FsfrjUjVIKtAa6lgAy%2FfvKvyCd6wK8XdfnhMJGoVXtTlwnJTq2ad4IAQ60rMQlbkyYjElcQa%2BrMqqwByhN7Aq9DsmFX5ZF%2B%2B%2FhvD38FanH9Z%2FeJFpjNlr8y%2Bvl5yqf4BPy5N7XZkqREdnFa1qu4rFIztDfmGkqtMvXP%2FoDnd4nPoMTJKwnkvlg2DA0o030o2FzdkIGvhyi4ZUz%2F6aqULx%2BUE97CTDS%2FI8Dz2taFYCLn%2BQhGgG4ZkERJWg8usq3kZh5Er%2FEFXIvq7kSE8885vknRMOBzP1L5%2FpvCszugcIxVQaoYXVHTCPvtujBjqyAR1yxywxSJ54ZKwyTUVLF5L69KaHK2JSUsB5fjpBm%2FK%2Fg4Jqa%2BGY3LEaT9Ff4wrJmdjlOL9CDZ6B%2FhTl1wMLy2x5iXUCHrP0XNtwrJSv%2BS9%2BW%2FJiL2DqvPgAL84ifz6cnRa%2BSMxUp2DdIWBEkXVwe8R4CM71IPdKRFb6BQjl7qTQwcEuSoqma2fLEMpVeIB5%2Bmt1oTepBSPB5FRgYwpOF5aZJrfoaNeEDJiWMsRhpXNXGac%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230531T060601Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYU4TSFEXH%2F20230531%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=253386764c1aa2398eaceec8d90b944cb4b2e6b4cc9539a61a3dbd1f8270708a&hash=b13896cb614ddf8633a8cb13f26710352b0cfcbafdfe0439074840ad38db2975&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0898122112005378&tid=spdf-0f37bd87-07ab-4cd2-a993-ed9af04abd3b&sid=58fce71660a7264db28b15922b9988613fc1gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f0c540000015651575a&rr=7cfd0749bad8a91a&cc=in),

Consider the system of coupled Black-Scholes equations (Regime-switching) for the value of a European put option:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma_1^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 V_1}{\partial S^2}+r S \frac{\partial V_1}{\partial S}-r V_1=\lambda_{12}\left(V_1-V_2\right) \\
V_1(0, t)=E e^{-r(T-t)} \\
\lim _{S \rightarrow \infty} V_1(S, t)=0 \\
V_1(S, T)=\max \{E-S, 0\}
\end{array}\right.
$$

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial V_2}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma_2^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 V_2}{\partial S^2}+r S \frac{\partial V_2}{\partial S}-r V_2=\lambda_{21}\left(V_2-V_1\right) \\
V_2(0, t)=E e^{-r(T-t)} \\
\lim _{S \rightarrow \infty} V_2(S, t)=0 \\
V_2(S, T)=\max \{E-S, 0\}
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $S$ is the value of the underlying asset, $t$ is the current time, $V_j(S, t)(j=1,2)$ is the option value when in state $j$ of the economy, $r$ is the risk-free interest rate (assumed to be constant), $E$ is the strike price and $T$ is the expiration time of the option.
We begin by introducing the following dimensionless variables
$$
q_j\left(x, \tau_j\right)=\frac{e^x V_j(S, t)}{E}, \quad x=\ln \left(\frac{S}{E}\right), \tau_j=\frac{\sigma_j^2}{2}(T-t)
$$
for $j=1$,2. Apart from the inclusion of the exponential factor in $q_j\left(x, \tau_j\right)$, the above change of variables for option valuation problems is a commonly adopted approach to normalize the PDE systems. The exponential factor is included to ensure that the $q_j\left(x, \tau_j\right)$ functions are integrable under the Fourier transform. With the new dimensionless variables, above system become
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \left\{\begin{array}{l}
-\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial \tau_1}+\frac{\partial^2 q_1}{\partial x^2}+\left(\gamma_1-3\right) \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x}-\left(2 \gamma_1+\beta_{12}-2\right) q_1=-\beta_{12} q_2 \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} q_1\left(x, \tau_1\right)=0 \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} q_1\left(x, \tau_1\right)=0 \\
q_1(x, 0)=\left(e^x-e^{2 x}\right)^{+}
\end{array}\right. \\
& \left\{\begin{array}{l}
-\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial \tau_2}+\frac{\partial^2 q_2}{\partial x^2}+\left(\gamma_2-3\right) \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial x}-\left(2 \gamma_2+\beta_{21}-2\right) q_2=-\beta_{21} q_1 \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} q_2\left(x, \tau_2\right)=0 \\
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} q_2\left(x, \tau_2\right)=0 \\
q_2(x, 0)=\left(e^x-e^{2 x}\right)^{+}
\end{array}\right.
\end{aligned},
$$
where $\gamma_j \equiv \frac{2 r}{\sigma_j^2}$ and $\beta_{j k} \equiv \frac{2 \lambda_{j k}}{\sigma_j^2}$, for $j, k=1,2 j \neq k$, which can be viewed as the interest rate and the rate of leaving each state, relative to the volatility from that state, respectively.

My doubt: I am pretty clear about the fact $$\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} q_1\left(x, \tau_1\right)=\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} q_2\left(x, \tau_1\right)=0, $$ as
$$\lim _{x \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{e^x V_j(S, t)}{E}=0,$$ But how can we see make sure $$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} q_1\left(x, \tau_1\right)=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} q_2\left(x, \tau_1\right)=0, $$ despite of $$\lim _{S \rightarrow \infty} V_1(S, t)=\lim _{S \rightarrow \infty} V_2(S, t)=0$$ due to the stigma with the factor $\frac{e^x}{E}$?

Comment: One confusing thing here (at least for me) is that you are using $\dfrac{e^x}{E}$, which is a variable, as a scaling factor for $V_j$. Is that allowed? I have always thought those should be constants. Your problem is with that factor after all. So either way, a different nondimensionalisation scheme would help.

Comment: I could not understand what is the problem with transformation $V_j \to q_j$, where $q_j=\frac{e^x}{E}V_j$. Can you be more specific about what you suggest by 'a different non-dimensionalisation scheme'? I think that can help me bit more. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your second to last line concerns only limits in the variable x, so given any fixed values for the other variables S, t, E what happens if x goes to negative infinity. The last line is a limit in S. You cannot just switch the limits but as far as I understand it you don't need to.

Comment: How can you fix $S=Ee^x$ while $x \to \pm \infty$?

Comment: @Riaz I seem to have overlooked that, too many variables in play. So you want to show $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^x V(Ee^x, \tau)=0$ only knowing $V(S,t) \rightarrow 0$ for large $S$. This is not true in general. It might follow somehow for the specific $V$ from the differential equation but I don't know anything about it.

Comment: not clear to me what exactly you are tying to convey.